# UItableVIew reusableCell adds the button at random cell after scrolling?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have tableview with `ReusableCellWithIdentifier` i am looking for the best solution.
I don't want to use **removesubview** method like below

```
if ([cell.contentView subviews]){
    for (UIBUtton *subview in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath Method. **I am used to get Button back with tag property. but with this button is added in diff rows in diff section while scrolling**.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdetifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdetifier];
        if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdetifier];
    }


  if ((indexPath.section==1 && indexPath.row==0) || (indexPath.section==3 && indexPath.row==1)) {
         cell.accessoryView = [self buttonWithMap:cell];

       }
   return cell;
}
```

Creating Buttonn

```
- (UIButton *)buttonWithMap:(UITableViewCell *)cell
{

    UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
    if (btn) {
        return btn;
    }
    else{

    UIButton *btnLocation = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btnLocation.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    btnLocation.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
    [btnLocation setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map_location.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnLocation addTarget:self action:@selector(setAddressBySelectLocation:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btnLocation setTag:101];
        return btnLocation;
    }
}
```

Comment: subclass UITableViewCell then you can 'reset' your cells in the prepareForReuse:

Comment: @CW0007007 But what the problem with this code. why i need to subclass?

Comment: @Sunnyshah When it reuses a cell, it'll still have the accessory view of the cell it reused, so you have to explicitly remove the old accessory view, even if you're not replacing it with anything.

Comment: @AlexBlundell but i have added the accessory view only for the particular rows of section. reuses a cell takes accessory view of another cell?

Comment: Subclassing will make this easier to handle explicit cell cases where the UI changes a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to set it to nil when condition  is not met, otherwise `tableView` gets confused:

```
if ((indexPath.section==1 && indexPath.row==0) || (indexPath.section==3 && indexPath.row==1)) {
    cell.accessoryView = [self buttonWithMap:cell];
}else{
    cell.accessoryView = nil;
}
```

Comment: Your code works for me. but cell accessoryView is added only for the particular rows of section. then why its taking for the all rows?

Comment: I know it's just for these 2 sections, but you still need to add code when it is not these section because cells are being reused